# Selenium .click() shifts the webpage and displays error: .... could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, webdriver

I am trying to automate a login to a site and this is how it looks when I initially get to the page:
[image: Click here to see]

and after I run the .click() command in Selenium, the page looks like this:

[image]

And throws this error:

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="classnamewashere"> could not be scrolled into view
```

My original code looks like this:

```
driver.get("website")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "u").send_keys("uname")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "p").send_keys("pword")

login = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")

login.click()
```

Based on my search here, I have tried:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', login)
```

before the .click()
and also

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'button')))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

Nothing is working. Do you know how I can get it to stop shifting? I don't even get a scroll bar the bottom of the page.  I have to reload it each time to get it back to normal.

EDIT:  This is now happening on another page, same site.  Any advice would be helpful please! Thank you!

Comment: We need to see that web page, but you didn't share the link

Comment: Sorry but its an internal company site so I cannot share the link.  I was trying to share as much as I could.  Anything specific you would need?

Answer (score 0):

I think this worked - I had to go up a level from the "`button`" tag to the "`form`" tag and use `.submit()`

```
login2 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
login2.submit()
```

EDIT: This is happening again where I don't have the form.  Any advice is helpful please! TIA!